# Getting TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I am currently facing the mentioned error by running a very simple code :

Code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time as t

def do_something():
       t.sleep(1)
       print("Done Sleeping")

p1 = mp.process(target=do_something)
p2 = mp.process(target=do_something)

p1.start()
p2.start()

p1.join()
p2.join()
```

I get

```
Error: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Not sure what really is wrong here. Can you help me understanding what is my mistake?

Comment: please could you clarify on what line exception throws?

Comment: FYI--the more recent (and simpler) method for Python multiprocessing is usage of [concurrent.futures module](https://pymotw.com/3/concurrent.futures/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Process class needs a capital P to be picked up.

Without the capital you are trying to instantiate the module: `multiprocessing.process`.

Try the following:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time as t

def do_something():
   t.sleep(1)
   print("Done Sleeping")

p1 = mp.Process(target=do_something)
p2 = mp.Process(target=do_something)

p1.start()
p2.start()

p1.join()
p2.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
p1 = mp.process(target=do_something)
p2 = mp.process(target=do_something)
```

To:

```
p1 = mp.Process(target=do_something)
p2 = mp.Process(target=do_something)
```